# How do I group mysqli_fetch_array results by matching dates?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to build a graph in morrisjs using php/mysql and need to output an object with the following format. It should group the period dates and then list the names following it for matching results:

```
{period: "2019-02-06 12:00:00", shelly: 2147483647, debra: 1240996571, sally: 2147483647, bill: 2147483647, bob: 619685085, jim: 126614618},
{period: "2019-02-06 12:30:00", shelly: 2147483647, debra: 1240996571, sally: 2147483647, bill: 2147483647, bob: 619685085, jim: 126614618},
{period: "2019-02-06 13:00:00", shelly: 2147483647, debra: 1240996571, sally: 2147483647, bill: 2147483647, bob: 619685085, jim: 126614618}
```

PHP:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($poolChart)) {
        $chart_data .= "{ \"period\": \"".$row["StatsHistoryTime"]."\", \"name\": \"".$row["name"]."\", \"hashrate\":".$row["hashrate"]."}, ";

    }
    $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
```

Currently my output looks like this

```
[
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:00:00",
    "name": "shelly",
    "hashrate": 2147483647
  },
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:00:00",
    "name": "debra",
    "hashrate": 1240996571
  },
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:00:00",
    "name": "sally",
    "hashrate": 2147483647
  },
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:00:00",
    "name": "bill",
    "hashrate": 2147483647
  }
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:30:00",
    "name": "shelly",
    "hashrate": 2147483647
  },
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:30:00",
    "name": "debra",
    "hashrate": 1460613388
  },
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:30:00",
    "name": "sally",
    "hashrate": 2147483647
  },
  {
    "period": "2019-02-06 12:30:00",
    "name": "bill",
    "hashrate": 2147483647
  }
]
```

Comment: Try `json_encode` - It's called JSON, JavaScript Object Notation.  It allows you to pass structured data as a string.   http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: What is your question? The title sounds like you want to use a `WHERE` clause on your query. This `Currently my output looks like this` sounds like it should be formatted differently? Also `rtrim` would be a better function than your `substr` usage.

Comment: I've updated the output example. I need to group the dates and then output the names matching after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve your problem is to get your data into an appropriate format (an array for each value of period, with other values in the array being the combination of each `name` and `hashrate`), and then you can use `json_encode` to convert that to the format required:

```
$chartdata = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($poolChart)) {
    $period = $row['StatsHistoryTime'];
    // have we already got data for this period?
    if (($k = array_search($period, array_column($chartdata, 'period'))) !== false) {
        // yes, update data for this period
        $chartdata[$k][$row['name']] = $row['hashrate'];
    }
    else {
        // no, create a new array
        $chartdata[] = array('period' => $period, $row['name'] => $row['hashrate']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($chartdata);
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
[
  {
    "period":"2019-02-06 12:00:00",
    "shelly":2147483647,
    "debra":1240996571,
    "sally":2147483647,
    "bill":2147483647
  },
  {
    "period":"2019-02-06 12:30:00",
    "shelly":2147483647,
    "debra":1460613388,
    "sally":2147483647,
    "bill":2147483647
  }
]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/c3F3p)